# Pasar datos de Activity a una clase

Tags: android, android-studio, activity

Resulta que quiero pasar datos de una actividad hacia una clase para utilizar los métodos de esa clase pero quiero enviar un dato desde la actividad instanciando la clase pero no me llega el dato, seguramente se hace de otro modo no lo sé, hace mucho tiempo que no utilizo android, a continuación el código.

```
public class Guardar {
   private String address="no llegan datos";

   //Intent intent=getIntent
   public String GetAddress(){
       return address;
   }

   public void setAddress(String address){
      this.address=address;
   }

}
```

A continuación la actividad

```
Guardar g=new Guardar();
g.setAddress(address);
```

Estuve revisando pero muchas personas solo utilizan datos entre actividades pero no hay información de como enviar datos a una clase o como utilizar los métodos de una clase correctamente de antemano gracias.

Comment: Hola la clase guardar como es una Clase solo puedes instanciarlo y crear un constructor que seran los variables que le estas asignando. Busca sobre los constructores :D

Comment: Explica un poco mejor qué es lo que no llega. Al ejecutar `g.setAddress(address);` ¿`address` tiene valor? ¿Estás seguro? Luego ¿cómo recuperas este valor de tu objeto `Guardar`? Muestra este código. Lo que te recomiendan de hacer un constructor es una falacia. No tiene ningún sentido, es mala praxis y fuera de lugar. ¡Ni caso! Danos un poco más de información para intentar ayudarte.

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev el dato address es la dirección MAC de un dispositivo bluetooth que quiero almacenar en la clase Guardar para evitar perder la conexión y que lo obtengo de un onClick que se hizo para una lista.

Answer (score 1):

**Si deseas enviar datos desde una Activity a una clase, lo aconsejable es realizarlo definiendo un constructor que reciba estos datos**, ejemplo:

```
public class Guardar {

 private String address="";

    //constructor
    public Guardar(String address) {
       this.address = address;
    }

   //Intent intent=getIntent
   public String GetAddress(){
       return address;
   }

  public void setAddress(String address){
      this.address=address;
  }
}
```

De esta forma al instanciar la clase `Guardar` puedes definir el valor:

```
Guardar g = new Guardar(address);
```

al realizar lo anterior puedes obtener el valor que originalmente definiste en la clase, ejemplo:

```
System.out.println("valor de address : " + g.getAddress());
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo pude solucionar, el error era que estaba creando nuevas instancias en cada activity y recordé la arquitectura singleton que permite acceder a una misma instancia desde cualquier clase.

```
public class Guardar {
    private String address=null;

    private static Guardar guardar;
    //permite que otras clases eviten la creación de una nueva instancia
    public static synchronized Guardar getInstance(){
        if(guardar==null){//verifica que no se haya instanciado la clase
            guardar=new Guardar();//crea la nueva instancia
        }
        return guardar;//devuelve la única instancia
    }
    //constructor de clase privado
    //evita que accedan al constructor
    private Guardar(){

    }

    public String GetAddress(){
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address){
        this.address=address;
    }

}
```

Comment: En realidad no es necesario que sea singleton. Lo que necesitas es la misma instancia de la clase Guardar para acceder a los datos guardados. Por eso te preguntaba _cómo recuperas el valor del objeto Guardar_.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una interfaz y hacer que la clase destino implemente dicha interfaz. O sea que obtienes una instancia de la actividad y le envías la información a la interfaz y con esto consigues que la clase destino contenga un método con la información pasada. Claro está que la interfaz debe contener un método que acepte por parámetros  un argumento del mismo tipo. Buena suerte

Comment: Sería bueno que añadieses código